# Want to find the max record among the records using pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to find the player who scored max no of runs against each team using pig.

```
Input : Inputs are in the below fashion
```

`Sachin 100 KXIP Hyderabad 1991
    sehwag 150 KXIP Hyderabad 1991
    Sehwag 100 MI Mumbai 2011
    Kohli 0 CSK Chennai 2014
    Dhoni 150 MI Hyderabad 1991
    Sachin 32 PW Chennai 2014
    Dhoni 150 MI Mumbai 2011`

    My Implementation:

    `record1= LOAD 'ipl.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as    (name:chararray,runs:int,team:chararray,loc:chararray,year:int);
    record2 = GROUP record1 by team as team;
    record3 = FOREACH record2 GENERATE group,MAX(record1.runs) as mx;
    record4= ORDER record3 by mx ASC;
    DUMP record4;`

```
 
    Output:
    (PW,32)
    (KXIP,150)
    (MI,150)

    But expecting the result in the following fashion..
    Sachin PW 32 Chennai 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

```
record1= LOAD 'ipl.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as    (name:chararray,runs:int,team:chararray,loc:chararray,year:int);
record2 = GROUP record1 by team;
record3 = FOREACH record2 GENERATE group,MAX(record1.runs) as mx;
record4 = JOIN record3 by (mx,group) LEFT OUTER, record1 by (runs,team);
record5 = FOREACH record4 GENERATE record1::name as name, record1::team as team, record3::mx as mx, record1::year as year;
record6= ORDER record5 by mx ASC;
DUMP record6;
```

produces the following result

```
(Kohli,CSK,0,2014)
(Sachin,PW,32,2014)
(sehwag,KXIP,150,1991)
(Dhoni,MI,150,1991)
(Dhoni,MI,150,2011)
```

notice that there are two records for Dhoni, this is because he scored 150 twice. If you want to remove that you need to choose the earliest or latest year depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using the TOP function : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/func.html#topx

Here is the script to obtain the result you want :

```
record1= LOAD 'ipl.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as 
(name:chararray,runs:int,team:chararray,loc:chararray,year:int);
record2 = GROUP record1 by team; 
record3 = FOREACH record2 GENERATE FLATTEN(TOP(1,1,record1));
record4= ORDER record3 by runs ASC;
DUMP record4;
```

As a result, you will get :

```
(Kohli,0,CSK,Chennai,2014)
(Sachin,32,PW,Chennai,2014)
(sehwag,150,KXIP,Hyderabad,1991)
(Dhoni,150,MI,Hyderabad,1991)
```